# How do I Combine Delete filter statements in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to be able to delete records from a table where ID is from 7970 to 9805 if sales amount is between 200 and 850.

I need your help.

Thank you in advance.

Here's my individual mysql delete statements.

```
DELETE FROM `fin_sales` WHERE `sale_id` BETWEEN 7970 AND 9805;

DELETE FROM `fin_sales` WHERE `total` BETWEEN 200 AND 850;
```

but its not working

Comment: So why not just use `and` ?

Comment: "It's not working" is not a problem description. What happens instead? Nothing? Too much? Computer explodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below query

```
DELETE FROM `fin_sales` WHERE `sale_id` BETWEEN 7970 AND 9805 AND `total` BETWEEN 200 AND 850;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you need to make one delete statement as below:

```
DELETE FROM fin_sales WHERE sale_id BETWEEN 7970 AND 9805 and total BETWEEN 200 AND 850;
```

I have not tested it so use it on your own discretion

Comment: Thank you too and your warning caption gave me heads up with precaution.